# What does "sister where it counts" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am confused about the meaning of dedication. Does it mean "sister, which I can rely on"?

> For Meghan, sister where it counts.

Sarah MacLean "A Rogue by Any Other Name"

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.  Is your sentence part of larger quotation?  As it stands, your sentence is not idiomatic.

Comment: Did you look up the verb "count"? Is that what confuses you, or is something else the issue? Please [be specific](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: MarcInManhattan, I do not understand the dedication, as I've said. I know the meaning of "count". But  what does it mean here?

Comment: EllieK, it is the single dedication at the begining of the book. No more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd understand this as meaning that Meghan is like a sister to the author in all the important ways - which would include traits like being able to rely on her, yes. It gives the reader the impression that Meghan would meet a list of idealised traits we feel a sister should have. It doesn't *necessarily* mean that Meghan is the author's actual sister, though that is a possibility; it might be that she is a good friend who fulfils everything an ideal sister would, or it might be that she is an actual sister who fulfils those traits "that count", i.e. the most important ones.

Comment: I agree with @Showsni. OP says it’s a dedication, so *for* means “[dedicated] to.”

Comment: @EllieK Yes, this is the dedication at the front of a book, so I wouldn't expect any other text around it. Similar to "For my Mum", "For John, with thanks for all the cups of tea" or "For my first grade teacher who said I'd never amount to anything".